# how to know number of installs for an app on windows store

Tags: store

In Windows Store for mobile apps, I see number of ratings for every app. Absolutely this is not the number of installs. So, how can I find how many times a mobile app on Windows store has been installed (like that in Google Play i.e. showing downloads)?

[image]

Now behold Google Play information for an app (Clash of Clans):

[image]

Comment: In theory, it shouldn't matter, as it doesn't mean much - the reviews should mean more...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, as a consumer of the App, you can't see the number of installations. That information is private to the developer.